# Is the check as accepted answer toggle positioned too close to the downvote toggle?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, user-interface, accepted-answer

This is somewhat a low priority IMO. I just thought that maybe I'm not the only who accidentally clicked the 'check as accepted answer' toggle when I'm supposed to click the downvote toggle.

Answer (score 2):

That is why it is a 'Toggle'....

Meaning you can undo something....

Like a *mistake*.....

Because us humans make those.....

not Jon Skeet though.....

He's not human....

He's like some weird robot that knows C....

and writes books....

and does other creepy robot stuff...

maybe the guys in the captcha were modeled after him...

hmm.....

did you know Jon Skeet has gold badges for tags I've never heard of?....

What is `linq`?....

maybe it is some creepy robot lingo for awesomeness...

did you know John Skeet has more gold badges than I have toes?....

it would be weird if I had 15 toes....

......

Thank you for your time.

Comment: On the contrary - I've accidentally flagged a comment as offensive before now when I meant to upvote it. I blame trying to click on a small target with my fingers on a phone at the same time as walking... unfortunately, that action *can't* be undone :(

Comment: @Chacha102, that's beside the point.

Comment: @Randell: It's *absolutely* to the point. If you do something accidentally but can immediately see that you've done it and easily undo that action, it really doesn't matter very much at all. If an action can't be undone, that makes it *much* more important to make sure it's not done accidentally.

Comment: We need `<rant></rant>` tags .... half of my answer would be inside them.

Comment: So you guys are okay accidentally clicking the wrong toggles at times?

Comment: Yes ... because I don't even have to refresh the page to see my mistake. It is instantaneous. So I can fix it really really quickly

Comment: Even if you can move the toggles away from each other a couple of pixels more?

Comment: @Randell: Even so, it's still going to be done reasonably often. As it's easily undoable I really don't mind much. I'd *far* rather the time was spent making comment upvote/flag toggle.

Comment: Even after the comment upvote/flag toggle has been done?

Comment: You don't mind much, but you do mind somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing you from unselecting an accepted answer, or even undoing a downvote. Therefore there is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem for a variety of reasons, but Jon Skeet's comment example of flagging a comment is *way* more valid of an example..